# How to convert date in milliseconds to localDate?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert date Long `1581420629955L` to LocalDate and then revert that.

To transform it in localDate, i use :

```
 final LocalDate localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1581420629955L).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate();
```

My `localDate` value is good => `2020-02-11`

And Then, i revert that with :

```
final GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonthValue(), localDate.getDayOfMonth());
final Long cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
final Long timeMilli = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

But my `timeMilli` is not equals to `1581420629955`. :(

**How can i do that ?**

Thanks :D

Comment: What is it equal to? What's missing? Does a `LocalDate` contain anything other than the year, month and day?

Comment: LocalDate as a data type does not have any information on anything other than the date. So it should be obvious that when converting data that contains info about the time (down to milliseconds precision) to a LocalDate and then back that this time-info will have to be lost in the process.

Comment: Yes but if i write 1592179200000L, the hours, minutes, seconds are 0. So how can i get the same result between 2 conversions ?

Comment: @Jérémy instead of using a GregorianCalendar object as a crutch you can convert your localDate back to your milliseconds with: `localDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to OH GOD SPIDERS, i finally use `localDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()`that solve my problem :D

Thanks for all yours responses !